# How to create a custom Python class to be used in Pipeline for dropping highly correlated features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pipeline

I'm using the Sklearn `Pipeline` + `GridSearchCV` for the data-preprocessing/hyperparameter tuning of a Deep Neural Network (regression).
For the preprocessing, I would need a custom class for dropping the highly correlated columns of the dataset. Here is my code (to be improved):

```py
class MyDecorrelator():
   
   def __init__(self, threshold):
       self.threshold = threshold
   
   def fit(self, X, y=None):
       return self
   
   def transform(self, X, y = None):
       correlated_features = set()  # Set of all the names of correlated columns
       corr_matrix = X.corr()
       for i in range(len(corr_matrix.columns)):
           for j in range(i):
               if abs(corr_matrix.iloc[i, j]) > self.threshold: # we are interested in absolute coeff value
                   colname = corr_matrix.columns[i]  # getting the name of column
                   correlated_features.add(colname)
       return X.drop(labels=correlated_features, axis=1, inplace=True)



def create_model(input_shape = 150, optimizer='adam', learn_rate=0.01, activation='relu', init='uniform', hidden_layers = 1, dropout = 0.5, hidden_size=64):
   # create model
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(input_shape, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init, ))
   for i in range(hidden_layers):
       model.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation=activation))
       model.add(Dropout(dropout), )
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
  # Compile model
   model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)
   return model


estimator = Pipeline([
           ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.0, 1.0))),
           ('decorrelation', MyDecorrelator(0.9)),
           ('feature_selector', SelectKBest()),
           ('kr', KerasRegressor(build_fn = create_model))
           ], verbose = True)

param_grid = [{
   'kr__optimizer': ['RMSprop', 'Adam'],
   'kr__epochs': [100, 300],
   #'kr__init': [ 'uniform', 'zeros', 'normal', ], 
   'kr__batch_size':[32, 128],
   'kr__learn_rate': [0.01, 0.1],
   'kr__activation': ['relu', 'sigmoid'],
   'kr__dropout': [0.9, 0.1],
   'kr__hidden_layers': [2, 3],
   'kr__hidden_size': [64, 128],
   'feature_selector__score_func': [mutual_info_regression],
   'feature_selector__k': [k],
   'kr__input_shape': [k]
}

for k in [50, 100] ]

grid = HalvingGridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=KFold(n_splits = 5), verbose=10)
```

but, when I try to run the `grid.fit(X, Y)`, it gives the following error:

```
'MyDecorrelator' object has no attribute 'set_params'
```

Furthermore, if I try to change the first line to  `class MyDecorrelator(BaseEstimator):`, it says

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'corr'
```

How to fix it?

**Update:**
I have corrected using the solution by Comsavvy, but as a result i get a warning: `UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan ...]`. How can it happen? It worked without the decorrelation.

Comment: I am not certain, but it seems you have fixed the first issue by having MyDecorrelator inheret from BaseEstimator which has the set_params functionas described in the documentation.


Now, you may be running into an issue that within HalvingGridSearchCv sklearn is calling your transform function with a numpy array rather than pandas dataframe. Numpy arrays (unlike pandas dataframes) do not have a .corr() attribute. Try np.corr() instead

Comment: (also double check the output is the same between pandas .corr() and np.corr() if it works)

Comment: Before we discuss what the problem actually is, `MyDecorrelator`'s class `transform()` method returns `X.drop(labels=correlated_features, axis=1, inplace=True)`. If `inplace=True` it actually returns nothing.

Comment: Also `MyDecorrelator` class has to inherit from both `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` to work effectively in the `Pipeline`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added ```TransformerMixin``` and changed to ```inplace = False```, but I still have the error above.

Comment: Check out the answer I posted and let see the result. @Gio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code runs correctly in this way,

```
class MyDecorrelator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.correlated_columns = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        correlated_features = set()  
        X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        corr_matrix = X.corr()
        for i in range(len(corr_matrix.columns)):
            for j in range(i):
                if abs(corr_matrix.iloc[i, j]) > self.threshold: # we are interested in absolute coeff value
                    colname = corr_matrix.columns[i]  # getting the name of column
                    correlated_features.add(colname)
        self.correlated_features = correlated_features
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        return (pd.DataFrame(X)).drop(labels=self.correlated_features, axis=1)
```

Comment: Good! You get all the highly correlated data during the fitting process and removed them in the `transform()` method. We don't actually need the `**kwargs` argument in the `transform()` method. This process is good compare to the previous one!

Comment: And also it's not a must you initialize `self.correlated_columns` as `None` in the `__init__()` method. You can remove it and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you change the `transform()` method of the `MyDecorrelator`'s class to the code below and let see the result,

```py
def transform(self, X, y = None):
       correlated_features = set()  # Set of all the names of correlated columns
       if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
           X = pd.DataFrame(X)
       corr_matrix = X.corr()
       for i in range(len(corr_matrix.columns)):
           for j in range(i):
               if abs(corr_matrix.iloc[i, j]) > self.threshold: # we are interested in absolute coeff value
                   colname = corr_matrix.columns[i]  # getting the name of column
                   correlated_features.add(colname)
       return X.drop(labels=correlated_features, axis=1)
```

This was simply done by testing if `X` is a DataFrame if it isn't then we change it to DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, your solution runs, but I have a plenty of non finite test scores (nan). I do not understand why.

Comment: If it runs, upvote my solution so as to motivate me.

Comment: I will suggest you mark this solution as "correct" by clicking the ✅ symbol. The test score is entirely another question.